# What are the equivalent CI commands for Vue projects based on Vite instead of the Vue CLI?

Tags: vue.js, cypress, eslint, vite, vitest

I created a new Vue project via `npm init vue@latest`. I used the Vue CLI before and want to get into Vite now. Inside my Github action I used the Vue CLI service commands before but now I'm looking for the equivalent commands using Vite.

---

**Check that the code style is fine (no errors, no warnings)**

Inside my workflow I previously used the command

`npm run lint -- --no-fix --max-warnings=0`

Based on the `lint` script command

`eslint . --ext .vue,.js,.jsx,.cjs,.mjs,.ts,.tsx,.cts,.mts --fix --ignore-path .gitignore`

I added the `lint:ci` script command

`eslint . --ext .vue,.js,.jsx,.cjs,.mjs,.ts,.tsx,.cts,.mts --max-warnings 0 --ignore-path .gitignore`

---

**Check that unit tests are passing**

Inside my workflow I previously used the command

`npm run test:unit`

Based on the `test:unit` script command

`vitest --environment jsdom`

I added the `test:unit:ci` script command

`vitest --environment jsdom --run`

---

**Check that e2e tests are passing**

Inside my workflow I previously used the command

`npm run test:e2e -- --headless`

There already is a `test:e2e:ci` script command and based on [the Cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/continuous-integration/github-actions) I think I have to use it this way (which worked for me)

```
  - name: Check if e2e tests are passing
    uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
    with:
      build: npm run build
      start: npm run test:e2e:ci
```

---

Do you have any better solutions? I'm not sure if this is the most elegant way or if Vue/Vite already provide some commands I don't know about yet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like you can't really use the `test:e2e:ci` command in GitHub actions. Instead, use the [Cypress workflow](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/continuous-integration/github-actions#Cypress-GitHub-Action) to automatically run the Cypress tests in your project.

Comment: vite is a build tool and, unlike `@vue/cli`, can be used with almost any framework (react, preact, vue, svelte, lit) or without one. It doesn't contain any preinstalled unit or e2e testing modules, you have to pick the one you like and add it yourself. Alternatively, you'll be able to find opinionated vite-based templates with various configurations. Pick one that's close to what you want, add what it misses and remove what you don't use.

Comment: thanks for your answers :) I read the Cypress docs and came to a solution. So this question now is all about "improvements"